# ios swift 3 xcode8 beta rounded imageView

Tags: ios, swift3

With my project I use the following code in order to make my images in rounded shape:

```
profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.width / 2
profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

I also use contrains for my image to make it `width = hight`, and other constrains.

After ugrading my project to **xcode 8 beta**, and swift 3. All the images views that I set to rounded were disappeared, and when I remove the code for making it rounded or I remove all the constrains they appear again.
But I still need them to be rounded. Anyone can help me to fix the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Check in the debugger, what the value of `profileImage.frame.size.width`. The layout might not have been completed at that time. Therefore, the corner radius might be set to an invalid value. Did you also upgrade to iOS 10 at the same time?

Comment: Apple also notes in the release notes that there are issues with the new IB file format (that have been mostly fixed in beta 5). I kept having views and constraints changing themselves in my storyboard.

Comment: With the cuurent version of xcode it work just fine, after the upgrade to xcode beta 5, all the images that i set rounded were disappear. I allways make sure that the width = hight. I set this using constrains.

Comment: Try moving this code to viewDidLayoutSubviews() since the width might be different at viewDidLoad() than after the constraints have been applied.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem, the solution was just to move a line of code before your layer modifications.
Try to apply layout changes:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

before your code:

```
profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.width/2
profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

**OR**

place your code related to frames / layers into `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.width/2
    profileImage.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much pedrouan. Its working just fine.

Comment: Just wasted one solid day trying to fix this issue :|

Comment: where to write self.view.layoutIfNeeded() ?

Comment: imageview is not getting round after writing this code override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.width/2
    profileImage.clipsToBounds = true

}