# ClipsToBounds working differently in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, cornerradius

The following code used to work before upgrading to Swift 3 where by it creates a circular image. However now the whole thing just becomes white. If I comment out the clips to bound part, the image appears but remains square.

Anyone know whats going on?

```
cell.truckImage.layer.cornerRadius =  cell.truckImage.frame.size.width / 2
cell.truckImage.clipsToBounds = true;
```

Comment: See the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954368/ios-swift-3-xcode8-beta-rounded-imageview

Comment: Add this line before setting corner radius self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Yup its a duplicate... head over to the other link for the answer