# How to make image view round in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, swift4

[image]Though there is solution of this question is present in internet, but I am unable to do so, I want to round a image.

this code I am using:

```
extension UIImageView {        
    func makeRounded() {
        let radius = self.frame.width/2.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
 }
```

then i call this function in viewdidload() like imgvw.makeRounded(). but it is not coming. please help

the previous link is not helping me

Comment: call in viewdidappear and check once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios swift 3 xcode8 beta rounded imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954368/ios-swift-3-xcode8-beta-rounded-imageview)

Comment: set `self.clipToBounds=true`

Comment: call this function in your viewDidLayoutSubView method

Comment: maybe frame.width = 0 -> the radius = 0, let call it in the viewdidappear or viewDidLayoutSubView

Comment: called in viewDidLayoutSubView or viewdidappear, it is not coming

Comment: called in viewDidLayoutSubView or viewdidappear, it is not coming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

  func makeRounded() {

    image.layer.borderWidth = 1
    image.layer.masksToBounds = false
    image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.height/2 //This will change with corners of image and height/2 will make this circle shape
    image.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Happy Coding

Comment: it is not coming sir

Comment: Did you changed the value of cornerRadius let say set .cornerRadius = 4.0. Just try to change this value according to your need

Comment: it is coming square sir i want round

Comment: yeah.. it is coming sir

Comment: Question was about image itself, not about when it added to controller

Comment: So the corner radius of the UIImageView is circular but the UIImageView centre width is too long that makes it not look like a circle shape. It is only circular at the sides. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will unnessecary call the function `makeRounded()` because it will get called EVERY TIME some layout happens in the superview. You should use this:

```
class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {

    @override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let radius = self.frame.width/2.0
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
        clipsToBounds = true // This could get called in the (requiered) initializer
        // or, ofcourse, in the interface builder if you are working with storyboards
    }

}
```

Set the class of your imageView to RoundedImageView

Comment: it is not coming sir

Comment: @GoribDeveloper If you excatly copy-paste this code !AND! set the class of your UIImageView to RoundedImageView, it should get rounded

Answer (score 0):

My code works well.

```
avatar.layer.borderWidth = 1
avatar.layer.masksToBounds = false
avatar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexString: "#39B44E").cgColor
avatar.layer.cornerRadius = avatar.frame.height/2 //This will change with corners of image and height/2 will make this circle shape
avatar.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score -2):

Create an extension for your class

```
extension ViewController: UIViewController{

    func makeRounded() {

        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2 
        clipsToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Then call use it

```
imageView.makeRounded()
```