# Make the UIImage to the rounded form?

Tags: swift, swift5

[image]

I tried the bellow code then I got the result like above image

Expected result for Image view is shown bellow

[image]

I  have posted the image of expectated result.

I have dragged the UIImage view and I want to make the image view that display in round format.
So please guide me out.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var imgView : UIImageView!
        imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1
           imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
           imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
           imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.width/2
           imgView.clipsToBounds = true
//I tried this still not getting the answer
```

Comment: SO is not coding service. Please you need to show what you have tried so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make image view round in swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790691/how-to-make-image-view-round-in-swift-4)

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do that like following

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    profilePhoto.layer.borderWidth = 1
    profilePhoto.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    profilePhoto.layer.masksToBounds = false
    profilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = profilePhoto.frame.width/2
    profilePhoto.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: I tried this option but not getting the expected result.

Comment: I'm using version swift 5

Comment: I have added the code which I already I tried before

Comment: yes I also tried this but not getting the result

Comment: Still not getting....

Comment: what is your `image view` width and height?

Comment: Width 350 Height 96

Comment: you should use equal width and height if you want to circle image view. suppose `width 240, height 240`. try with this.

Comment: ok I'll try this option but what if both height and width are different

Comment: Not working yet.... Is there any other way????

Comment: Got my answer...

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView is subclass of UIView. Each UIView has its own CALayer. You can set the border color, border width and corner radius of the view by using its layer. To show the UIImageView in circular shape, first height and weight of the view should be equal and then set corner radius as height/2 or width/2.

If myImage is UIImageView for which height and weight are equal, then:

```
    myImage.layer.cornerRadius = myImage.frame.size.height / 2
```

Comment: I tried this but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can round an `imageView` using the `CALayer`, use this class to do it in the storyboard:

```
@IBDesignable class RoundImageView: UIImageView
{
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? = nil
        {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var dropShadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowOffset = dropShadowOffset
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var maskToBounds: Bool = true {
        didSet{
            layer.masksToBounds = maskToBounds
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var dropShadowColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowColor = dropShadowColor?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var dropShadowRadius: CGFloat  = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowRadius = dropShadowRadius
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** You can do this by using custom view class. Create a new swift file and set name to UIImageViewX then paste the below code.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class UIImageViewX: UIImageView {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBInspectable public var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var pulseDelay: Double = 0.0

    @IBInspectable var popIn: Bool = false
    @IBInspectable var popInDelay: Double = 0.4

    // MARK: - Shadow

    @IBInspectable public var shadowOpacity: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            //layer.shadowOpacity = Float(shadowOpacity)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            //layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            //layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var shadowOffsetY: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            //layer.shadowOffset.height = shadowOffsetY
        }
    }

    // MARK: - FUNCTIONS
    override func layoutSubviews() {
//        super.layoutSubviews()
//        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
//        layer.shadowOpacity = Float(shadowOpacity)
//        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
//        layer.masksToBounds = false
//        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
    }


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if clipsToBounds && shadowOpacity > 0 {
            layer.masksToBounds = true
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

            // Outer UIView to hold the Shadow
            let shadow = UIView(frame: rect)
            shadow.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            shadow.layer.masksToBounds = false
            shadow.layer.shadowOpacity = Float(shadowOpacity)
            shadow.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
            shadow.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
            shadow.layer.shadowOffset.height = shadowOffsetY
            shadow.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath

            shadow.addSubview(self)
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if pulseDelay > 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: pulseDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }, completion: nil)
        }

        if popIn {
            transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: popInDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Step2:**

[image]

Set custom class in storyboard like above image.

**Step3:**

After this you can see the corner radius properties of imageview in Attribute section.
[image]

Increase and decrease the corner radius then you will got the desire result

Comment: Not working... as shown in output I'm getting the result after trying your option